# Sending open file in a request fails on repeating

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code:

```
import requests

url = # any API that accepts file in request

with open("/mnt/d/a.png", "rb") as file:
    for i in range(3):
        ts = requests.post(url, files={"file": file})
        print(ts)
```

Output was:

```
<Response [200]>
<Response [500]>
<Response [500]>
```

Why does it fail after the first time?

Surprisingly it does not fail if I do it this way:

```
for i in range (3):
    with open("/mnt/d/a.png", "rb") as file:
        file_dict = {"file": file}
        a = {"files": file_dict}
        ts = requests.post(url, **a)
        print(ts)
```

Giving the following output:

```
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
```

I checked `print(file)` and `print(type(file))`, before the request, nothing changed in either of the tries.

Comment: Once a file has been read any additional reads will return nothing, the first request reads the contents of the file, then the subsequent requests try to read the file but get nothing

Comment: is there a way to open a file and read it as many times as I require? In my case, the file needs to open first and then the loop runs.

Comment: You could use [seek(0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) to manually set the file stream back to the start. Honestly not sure which would perform better, reopening the file or using seek

Comment: Fix your indentation errors in your posted code!!!

Comment: file.seek(0) works for me, thanks. You cn add the above as an answer.

Comment: @SumantAgnihotri This is an English-language site -- we try not to use old Anglo-Saxon words! :-)